# Get authorization id from express checkout

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using the paypal-python-sdk.

Currently, I'm redirecting the user to paypal where they log in, click confirm, and are redirected back to my site.  No issues there.  However, I have no idea how to get the `authorization id` so I can capture the amount authorized (or smaller).  According to the docs its supposed to exist under `related_resources` but the list is always empty.

Will authorizations completed by logging into paypal return an authorization id?

Clarification: I know I can execute the payment with the `payment_id`.  However, executing the payment is out of the question because I must be able to capture less than authorized.

```
request = {
    "intent": "authorize",
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": PAYPAL_RETURN_URL,
        "cancel_url": PAYPAL_CANCEL_URL
    },
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "total": str(self.order.total),
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "description": "Lorem lipsum"
    }]
}
payment = Payment(request, api=self._connection())
```

Comment: Not a python person, but [this is the flow](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/capture-payment/) you'll need to "auth and capture" (more or less than "authed" amount). Hth...

Comment: @EdSF I could kiss you... thank you so much.